# How to fetch LAST_INSERT_ID() immediately after row is inserted using connector/python driver (MySQL)

Tags: python, mysql

So this is my schema,

```
TABLE articles

id -> AUTO_INCREMENT_VALUE
article_name -> STRING
```

`Insert into articles(id,article_name) values (NULL,'Harry Potter')`

There are many concurrent transactions occuring per second,

I'm executing this using connector/python driver for MySQL.

Is there any way i can get the LAST_INSERT_ID() in just one query along with insert?

Also is this safe?  What if another insert has already occurred concurrently?

Comment: newID = db.insert_id();

Comment: `cursor.lastrowid` 

fetches the LAST_INSERT_ID() in connector python

Answer (score 3):

`cursor.lastrowid` fetches the last auto_incremented value in connector/python

Also, the function is safe for using in concurrent transactions